# Go ChromeDP ignores any external or internal css during printing to pdf and uses only those, that in html file ONLY

Tags: go, chromedp

Go ChromeDP not using any css either internal or external styles (only those, that was written in html, not other file). I using method

```
page.SetDocumentContent(frameTree.Frame.ID, string(buf.Bytes())).Do(ctx)
```

to add html file to chromedp, and

```
buf, _, err: = page.PrintToPDF().Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
_, err = outputBuf.Write(buf)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

to print to pdf, but pdf in result not styled (even with external css fileserver). I tried to add it with `page.GetResourceTree().Do(ctx)` + `css.CreateStyleSheet(resourceTree.Frame.ID).Do(ctx)` +

```
css.SetStyleSheetText(stylesheet, `.c {
     color: red;
     font-size: 30px;
     background-color: aqua;
}
`).Do(ctx)
```

and it worked, but it sad to use it every time I want generate pdf, especially in my case, because I am using html from html/template. Maybe there are easy way to add external css into single html file? What do you think?

Thanks for any answer

Bohdan

I want to convert go template with external css, images and font into pdf using chromedp, but it ignored anything beyond main html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that external resources take time to load. You should wait for them to be loaded. When the page is ready, the `Page.loadEventFired` event is raised. So we can wait for this event and print the page afterward. See the demo below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/page"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Simulate a network latency.
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")
        fmt.Fprint(w, `h1 {font-size: 100pt; color: red;}`)
    }))
    defer ts.Close()

    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    // construct your html
    html := `<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="%s/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    </body>
</html>
`

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("about:blank"),
        // setup the listener to listen for the page.EventLoadEventFired
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            lctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
            chromedp.ListenTarget(lctx, func(ev interface{}) {
                if _, ok := ev.(*page.EventLoadEventFired); ok {
                    wg.Done()
                    // remove the event listener
                    cancel()
                }
            })
            return nil
        }),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            frameTree, err := page.GetFrameTree().Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return page.SetDocumentContent(frameTree.Frame.ID, fmt.Sprintf(html, ts.URL)).Do(ctx)
        }),
        // wait for page.EventLoadEventFired
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            wg.Wait()
            return nil
        }),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            buf, _, err := page.PrintToPDF().Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return os.WriteFile("sample.pdf", buf, 0644)
        }),
    ); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("done!")
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1152.

Comment: thank you very much, you are my savior :D

I found similar code but it not worked for me, I think i just wrote it wrong, but you really helped

thx :)